# Accessory tap not recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table with static cells. One cell as a disclosure indicator (as well as a text view). The disclosure indicator is set up to fire a segue as an accessory action. But the segue doesn't fire. And it definitely used to, this segue was an early addition to my app and was working for quite a while.

I've tried putting a breakpoint in the `tableView(accessoryButtonTapped)` method and it doesn't get called. (I also set up breakpoints in the various segue methods but of course the accessory tap would come first anyway)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Disclosure indicators are not tappable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for accessoryType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623228-accessorytype), the only accessory type that tracks touches is the detailDisclosureButton:

> If the cell is enabled and the accessory type is
>   detailDisclosureButton, the accessory view tracks touches and, when
>   tapped, sends the data-source object a
>   tableView(_:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith:) message.

Comment: Thanks. I had also disabled selection for the table, so once I moved the segue from the accessory to the cell itself, and enabled single selection, it worked!